# do I have to call all the exposed dispose functions of the controls within a windows form in the overriden dispose function?

Tags: winforms, controls, dispose

I have a windows form that contains many controls e.g timers, gridviews, and binding sources etc, and all of these expose a dispose function. Do I have to call their dispose function in this

```
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {

        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        // do I have to write something here ???
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

also what does components.Dispose() exactly do?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally when you add controls onto your forms via the toolbox in Visual Studio, the controls will automatically be `Disposed` for you (in the `protected override void Dispose` method).

The only time you do need to manually dispose objects is when you *manually* create other disposable objects that implement the `IDisposable` interface, things like file handles (`Stream`, `StreamReader`...), GDI objects (`Bitmap`, `Brush`) and unmanaged resources. Manually releasing objects of this type ensure you follow good coding practice by releasing the resources you create.

Answer (score 0):

No, the form will call Dispose for you.

What is Dispose for? This is taken from here [IDispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx)

> Use the Dispose method of this
>   interface to explicitly release
>   unmanaged resources in conjunction
>   with the garbage collector. The
>   consumer of an object can call this
>   method when the object is no longer
>   needed

Answer (score 0):

The `base.Dispose` call invokes the `System.Windows.Forms.Form.Dispose`, which disposes menus and other form controls. The call ends up in `System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose`, which recursively disposes all child controls.

I guess you don't need to worry as long as your control is reachable from the form, either directly or transitively.